# How to save a MutableList with SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I want to save and get a `MutableList` using `SharedPreferences` in my Android app.

I tried this, but it's not correct:

```
private fun saveFavorite(saveFavorite : MutableList<String>) {
    val sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) ?: return
    with(sharedPref.edit()) {
        putStringSet("lastFavorite",saveFavorite)
        apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: that code is not saving anything it's just example i want the way ( code ) to store a mutable List

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`putStringSet()` receives a `Set<String>`, you can convert your `MutableList<String>` to set doing:

```
putStringSet("lastFavorite", saveFavorite.toSet())
```

And then, you can convert it back to a `MutableList<String>` when you retrieve it:

```
getStringSet("lastFavorite", setOf<String>()).toMutableList()
```

Be aware that using StringSet **won't preserve the order** of the elements when reading them back in, as SharedPreferences uses a HashSet. Also, **it does not support duplicate elements**.

If your use case requires to store an ordered list that supports duplicate elements, consider marshalling the list and save it as a single string.

For example, concatenating all the strings together using a character that won't be contained in your strings as a delimiter (e.g., `|`). Then you can `split()` them apart when reading them back in.

If the list is too long, then you should consider a different data store.